# Rigid boolean inclusions?

Tags: set-theory, forcing, boolean-algebras

A boolean algebra $B$ is *rigid* if it has no nontrivial automorphisms and *atomless* if it has no minimal nonzero elements. $A \subseteq B$ is a *complete boolean inclusion* if $B$ is complete and $A$ is a complete subalgebra of $B$; call it a *rigid inclusion* if $B$ has no nontrivial automorphism that leaves each $A$-element fixed.

**Can there exist a proper, rigid, complete boolean inclusion $A \subseteq B$ such that $A$ and $B$ are nonrigid, atomless$^*$ boolean algebras?**

My Google searches turned up nothing here. However I found a kind of operator-algebra analog, R. Longo's "Simple injective subfactors," which are rigid *-algebraic inclusions of von Neumann algebras. It might be possible to derive from his construction a rigid boolean inclusion that gives an affirmative answer to the question. But I'd like to know if anyone else has thought about this question, or can see quickly that the answer must be negative.

======

$^*$I specify "atomless" here because an uninteresting example can be constructed if $A$ is allowed to have atoms. Let $C$ be any rigid complete boolean algebra; let $B$ be the cartesian product $C \times C$ with pointwise operations (in forcing terms, the "lottery sum" of two copies of $C$), i.e. a boolean algebra having an element $x \in B$ such that $\{ y \in B : y \leq x \}$ and $\{ y \in B : y \leq \neg x \}$ are both isomorphic to $C$; let $A \subseteq B$ be the complete subalgebra $\{ 1, x, \neg x, 0 \}$: then $A$ and $B$ are both nonrigid (each having an automorphism that exchanges $x$ and $\neg x$), but $B$ rigidly includes $A$, since any nontrivial automorphism of $B$ that fixed $x$ and $\neg x$ would have to act as a nontrivial automorphism on either $\{ y \in B : y \leq x \}$ or $\{ y \in B : \ y \leq \neg x \}$ (or both), which is impossible because these are rigid.

Comment: So you're asking if there's a forcing $\Bbb P$ that has a subforcing $\Bbb Q$ such that neither is rigid, but the quotient is rigid?

Comment: It's a good idea to put the question in terms of forcing; let me try to do so. Let $\mathbb{P}$ denote $A$, and let $\dot{\mathbb{Q}}$ be a $\mathbb{P}$-name for a boolean algebra such that $\mathbb{P} \ast \dot{\mathbb{Q}} = B$. If $\dot{\mathbb{Q}}$ is what you mean by the "quotient" then it seems easy to make $\dot{\mathbb{Q}}$ rigid but $\mathbb{P}$ and $\mathbb{P} \ast \dot{\mathbb{Q}}$ non-rigid (let $\mathbb{P}$ be a non-rigid forcing and let $\dot{\mathbb{Q}}$ be a rigid forcing in the ground model, so the iteration reduces to product forcing). [continued ...]

Comment: So I think (not 100% sure) what I'm asking is different and could be posed equivalently as follows. Let $\mathbb{P}$ and $\mathbb{P} \ast \dot{\mathbb{Q}}$ be non-rigid, let $G$ be generic on $\mathbb{P} \ast \dot{\mathbb{Q}}$; let $S$ be the set of all generic filters $F$ on $\mathbb{P} \ast \dot{\mathbb{Q}}$ such that $V[F] = V[G]$; note $S$ has $> 1$ member due to non-rigidity, but (I think this is my question) could it be the case that each $F \in S$ is uniquely specified by its restriction to $\mathbb{P}$?

Comment: Following Asaf’s suggestion, I think this is possible. You can first add a Cohen-generic subset of $\omega_1$ and then shoot clubs in a rigid way.  Assuming CH, the two-step iteration will be equivalent to adding one Cohen subset, which is homogeneous.  There might be a simpler way...

Comment: Agree the best way to get an example is probably to think about it as iterated forcing this way, though I don't see how the details would go, in the proof that you get a rigid boolean inclusion. If there is an example like this, the next question would be whether there's an example where the "quotient" $\dot{\mathbb{Q}}$ is *also* nonrigid (in $V^\mathbb{P}$).

Comment: If the second step is nonrigid, then the whole iteration is nonrigid. This is maybe most immediate through consideration of names for distinct generics that generate the same model.

Comment: Having thought more about your suggestions, I believe Asaf is exactly right that a "rigid boolean inclusion" $A \subseteq B$, as I defined it, is one that can be decomposed as $A$ and an iterated-forcing-step quotient algebra that is rigid. Am still working on proving this explicitly, using the definition of the quotient algebra of $B$ modulo an ideal dual to $G \cap A$ etc., but I expect it will work out.

Comment: In this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1305.2058 Thm. 3.15 I address a very similar  type of issue. What is shown is that for any non rigid SSP $B$ there is a $B$-name $\dot{Q}$  which is forced to be SSP by $B$ such that in $V[H]$ with $H$ $V$-generic for $C=B\ast\dot{Q}$ there is exactly one $V$-generic $G$ for $B$ such that $C/G$ is SSP in $V[G]$. It is weaker than what you want but may be reworking on it you can strengthen it to the desired conclusion. The idea for proving the theorem is in line with what Monroe Eskew suggests.